# Why is my code throwing error in this C code?

Tags: c, debugging, linked-list, runtime-error

I'm fairly new to C and was trying to implement linked list in C. In the part of code which is supposed to add a node to an empty linked list or insert a node to the beginning of the list, the latter works but throws error on trying to add a single node to empty linked list. Rest of the program works fine.

EDIT : I ran the code on online GDB debugger and it shows error in line 111. If I remove that block of code, it doesn't throw error anymore. But, I still can't figure out why it throws error there.

Segmentation fault.
0x0000000000400927 in AddAfter () at main.c:111
111        while (prevNode->next != NULL)

Here's [my code](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/e1878072841f9d022b2c3cc45493919d) with more details.

```
/*
# main() is at the bottom.

*/


#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <Windows.h>

typedef struct node
{
  int data;
  struct node * next;
} node;

//Global Variable
node* head = NULL;


node* createList()
{
 int n;
 printf("Loading...\n");
 Sleep(1);
 printf("How many nodes would you like to have in the list ?\n");
 scanf("%d",&n);

 int i;
 node* temp = NULL;
 node* nodeJumper = NULL;

 for (i = 0; i<n; i++)
 {
   temp = malloc(sizeof(node));
   printf("Enter node %d : ",i+1);
   scanf("%d", &(temp->data));
   temp->next = NULL;

   if (head == NULL)
     head = temp;

   else
   {
     nodeJumper = head;
     while (nodeJumper->next != NULL)
        nodeJumper = nodeJumper -> next;
     nodeJumper->next = temp;
   }
 }
 printf("Sucessfully created\n\n");
 return head;
}


void printList()
{
 node* nodeptr = NULL;
 if (head == NULL)
    printf("The list is empty.");
 else
   {
    nodeptr = head;
    printf("Your Linked List : ");
    while(nodeptr != NULL)
      {
        printf(" %d>", nodeptr->data);
        nodeptr = nodeptr->next;
      }
    printf("\n\n");
    }

}


int countNode()
{
 node* temp = head;
 int count = 0;
 while (temp!= NULL)
  { count++;
    temp = temp-> next;
  }
 return count;
}


void AddAfter()
{
 int pos, data;
 printf("Loading...\n");
 Sleep(1);
 printf("Enter position number to insert new node: ");
 scanf("%d",&pos);

 printf("Enter a number to enter in the list: ");
 scanf("%d", &data);


 int count = countNode(); //Count no. of nodes in linked list
 int i;
 node* prevNode = head; //node before inserted new node.

 node* temp = malloc(sizeof(node));
 temp->data = data;



  if (pos == count+1) //Append the list
  {
   while (prevNode->next != NULL)
      prevNode= prevNode->next;
   temp->next = NULL;
   prevNode->next = temp;
  }

  else if (pos == 1) //Throws error while trying to add node to empty linked list
  {
   temp->next = head;
   head = temp;
  }

  else if (pos <= count && pos >= 1)
  {
   for (i=1; i< pos-1; i++)
     prevNode = prevNode->next;
   temp->next = prevNode->next;
   prevNode->next = temp;
  }
  else //Invalid positions input by user.
  {
   printf("Request unsucessful\n");
   printf("Only positions 1 to %d are valid", count+1);
  }

}


int printMenu()
{
 int option;
 printf("Select options from menu:\n");
 printf("1> Create Linked List\n2> Add nodes anywhere in the linked list\n3> Quit\n\n");
 printf("Enter option number here: ");

 scanf("%d",&option);
 return option;
}


int main()
{
 printf("\n\t### Welcome to Linked list manager ###\n\n");

 while(1)
 {
   int userChoice = printMenu();

   if (userChoice == 1)
   {
    head = createList();
    printList();
   }


   else if (userChoice == 2)
   {
    AddAfter();
    printf("\n");
    printList();
   }

   else if (userChoice ==3)
   {
    exit(0);
   }

   else
   {
    printf("Enter a valid option number.\n");
   }
 }

return 0;
}
```

I have been trying to figure out for hours. Any guidance would be much appreciated.

Comment: Can you please put the error in the question and not as an external link or image? This is probably a pointer error, so put it in your debugger and find out what the situation is just before it crashes.

Comment: Debugging is about finding the exact place where what you _think_ the program is doing diverges from what it's _actually_ doing. You can use a debugger. Or you can add `printf`s. Or you can carefully trace each line by hand with pencil and paper. Asking someone else to debug for you is not the way to master these techniques.

Comment: gdb lets you examine variables (try the `info locals` command). See which one doesn't have a value you expect it to have.

Comment: Just a knee-jerk reaction, what happens if "prevNode" is either invalid or NULL?  If you run "option 2" prior to running "option 1", then "head" will be NULL, and you'll segv.  You should add a check in "AddAfter" to validate that "head" isn't NULL.

Comment: @TonyB I guess I figured out. When I try to insert one node in empty linked list, countNode() returns 0 as head is NULL at that point and hence the first 2 conditional statements(if and else if) conflict as they both will evaluate to True.

Comment: Why not make that an answer, to get this out of the list of unanswered questions?

Comment: What is your input?

Answer (score 0):

Just a knee-jerk reaction, what happens if "prevNode" is either invalid or NULL? If you run "option 2" prior to running "option 1", then "head" will be NULL, and you'll segv. You should add a check in "AddAfter" to validate that "head" isn't NULL.